# Best method to add a new column with default value

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have a postgresql DB and a table with almost 40 millions of rows. when I try to add a new column with default value:

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1
ADD COLUMN col1 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Its taking 15 min+ . Is there any other way which we can set to default value with minimum downtime

Comment: You could make the column nullable, not assign a default value, and then introduce zero as a default value via `COALESCE` when you actually do the query.  Skipping the step of assigning a default value should save you time.

Answer (score 1):

You should first add Column

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD COLUMN col1 integer  DEFAULT 0;
```

then you should writer update query to set

```
Update table1 set col1=0
```

Comment: If you add the column with `default 0` updating the table afterwards makes no sense whatsoever because all columns will already have that default value.